# SoapUI how to check the count of number of items returned in response

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

is there is way to check the count of the items returned. basically I have a soap service which can return list of data items, is there an easy way to have an assert statement to check the count of the list? tried groovy script but didn't have much luck

Answer (score 5):

You can add and assertion of XPath Match type in your testStep, and there check the condition. i.e you have a response similar to:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <myRoot xmlns:nt="http://mynamespace/">
        <list>
            <element>data1</element>
            <element>data2</element>
            <element>data3</element>
        </list>
      </myRoot>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[image]

Then add in your assertion the next XPath `count(//*:myRoot/*:list/*:element)` and set the expected result, in this case `3`:

[image]

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create a XPath Match assertion. Use the count() function.

There is a website that is a nice reference for all the XPath functions: http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XPath_2.html#Functions~count